# What is the value $f(-4)$ in the under function such that $f(x)+f(\frac1x)=\frac{x^2-12x+1}{2x}.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, functional-equations

Let $f$ is a function such that 
$$f(x)+f(\frac{1}{x})=\dfrac{x^2-12x+1}{2x}.$$
Then what is the value $f(-4)=$?

Comment: @ZackNi. Thanks

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Comment: @Did Yes it should the left arrow rather than right arrow. I don't know how to type it. Could you help me out?

Comment: @ZackNi You could repost your comment, using words instead of this symbol.

Comment: $\dfrac{x^2-12x+1}{2x} = \frac{x}{2} -3 + \frac{1}{2x}-3 =f(x) + f(\frac{1}{x}) $this function $f(x) = \frac{x}{2}-3$ satisfying the condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rewriting would give

$f(x)+f(\frac{1}{x})=\dfrac{x^2-12x+1}{2x}=\frac{1}{2}(x+\frac{1}{x})-6$

Then, it is easy to see a possible function is

$f(x)=\frac{1}{4}(x+\frac{1}{x})-3$

So, if you put $\frac{1}{x}$ in the argument, you would get the same function back.

However, as mentioned in comments, $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}-3$ is also a valid solution. Therefore , more conditions are required to find a unique function.

Comment: ZackNi and Med have different results. If $f_1$ and $f_2$ are solutions of the equation then any convex combination of this functions is a solution of the equation.

Comment: @Rafal, I think you are right. Different functions would satisfy the condition. So, I would say, we need more conditions to pinpoint a unique function. Thank you.